# How can I change the color of a Folium marker in a HeatMapWithTime based on the frame being displayed?

Tags: pandas, folium

My project involves a dataframe with data on trash containers located across my university's campus over 365 days. Each row of the dataframe includes the date when a container was emptied, its address, the amount of trash it contained, and its latitude and longitude.

Using this data, I created a HeatMapWithTime that displays black circle markers for each trash container site on the map. The heatmap shows the tonnage of trash collected from each site and how those change over 365 days.

I want to highlight the container with the highest tonnage for each day on the HeatMapWithTime. To do this, I want to change the marker color of that container to red (or add a red circle around its location), but only for that specific day. If that container no longer has the highest tonnage for the day, the marker should disappear, and a new marker should appear around the container that has the highest tonnage for the day.

This is my first post here, so please forgive me if my post needs to be adjusted or isn't formatted properly.

Here is my python code:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMapWithTime, HeatMap

# create a map centered on Boston
map_center = [42.3601, -71.0589]
dynamic_heat_map = folium.Map(location=map_center, zoom_start=12)
    
    
for index, row in geocoded_df.groupby('Address').first().iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker(
        location=[row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
        radius=2,
        fill_opacity=0,
        color='black',
        tooltip=row['Processed Address']
    ).add_to(dynamic_heat_map)




# create a HeatMapWithTime layer
heat_data = []
for Date in geocoded_df['Date'].unique():
    data = geocoded_df.loc[geocoded_df['Date'] == Date, ['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Tons']].groupby(['Latitude', 'Longitude']).sum().reset_index().values.tolist()
    heat_data.append(data)
    


HeatMapWithTime(
    data=heat_data,
    index=geocoded_df['Date'].unique().tolist(),
    auto_play=True,
    use_local_extrema=True,
    name='Tons'
).add_to(dynamic_heat_map)



# # display the map
dynamic_heat_map
```

I tried collecting the max weights for each container and plotting a marker for them, but I ended up with red markers on all of my containers at the same time, where as I am trying to have each marker appear only if that container has the highest tonnage for that specific day. I can't figure out how to implemented like I described in the problem details. (keep in mind that this attempt was removed from the code shown above as it did not work)